# User link in HNQ list on StackExchange.com breaks when user is deleted

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, broken-link, deleted-accounts

It doesn't happen that often, but when a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/91551/20215) by a deleted user becomes a Hot Network Question, the [link to the user](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users//user34693) on the [Hot Questions page on StackExchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) breaks:

[image]

From the URL itself, `https://movies.stackexchange.com/users//user34693`, it's clear that the user ID is missing. In cases like this, it's better to remove the link altogether and just show the username as plain text.